# Why is the left side of my image in the center instead of the actual center?

Tags: css, image, position

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the image block to the center of the banner.  What's happening is the left edge of the image is what's in the center.  How would I get the actual center of the image to the center of the banner?  I hope this makes sense... lol.

Here is what I am currently getting:
[image]

This is what I am trying to get... you can ignore the differences in fonts, borders, etc.. lol
[image]

This is my css:

```
#profile-banner {
    background: #000;
    height: 267px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#profile-banner h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: Piximisa;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#profile-banner p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

#profile-banner .logo {
    top: 125px;
    background: #333;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="profile-banner">
     <h1>Some Team Name</h1>
     <p>
         Some catchy slogan.
     </p>
     <img src="{BLANK-LOGO}" alt="" border="0" class="logo">
</div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Learn how to use StackOverflow.

Comment: Why did you give a `top: 125px;` and `position: absolute;` to the `.logo`?

Comment: remove the position:absolute from the .logo

Comment: @ Praveen : I added top: 125px so that the the vertical-middle of the image would be aligned with the bottom of the banner(E.G. the wide black box)... and the absolute position gives it a true vertical centering.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix absolute and static positioning. You can use absolute positioning:

```
position: absolute;
top: 125px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -125px;
```

or static positioning:

```
margin: 125px auto 0;
```

The main difference is how the element affects other elements. Using absolute positioning takes the element out of the document flow, so it doesn't affect other elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your CSS this way**

```css
#profile-banner .logo {
    margin: 125px auto 0;
    background: #333;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Changes**

1. Remove `position` and `top`.
2. Add the `top` as `margin-top`.
3. Positioned elements do not respect margins.